How can I retrieve the highlighted link of each ad from the Facebook Ads Library using Selenium?
I’m trying to use Selenium to extract highlighted links from ads in the Facebook Ads Library. The issue I’m encountering is a TimeoutException when attempting to locate elements. Here's the code I'm using:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

cService = ChromeService(executable_path='C:/web scraping files/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=cService)

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=active&ad_type=all&country=US&media_type=all&q=%20mug&search_type=keyword_unordered')

title_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="js_16a"]/a/span')))

for element in title_elements:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
    print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="js_16q"]/a')))])

enter image description here
Issue:
I’m encountering the following error:
Cell In[31], line 1 elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="js_162"]/a'))) File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:105 in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) TimeoutException 
Question:

What might be causing this TimeoutException?
How can I modify my code to correctly retrieve the highlighted link for each ad?
Is there a better way to identify and interact with the elements to get the desired data?

